# How to add attachments to e-mail on curl

Tags: c, curl

I want to attach a text file to the message, which is located in the folder with the program, but I can't. A file with a size of 0 bytes is attached.

```
#define FROM    "<name_mail@gmail.com>"
#define TO      "<name1_mail@gmail.com>"
#define TITLE     "MY_NAME" FROM

static const char *payload_text[] = {
  "To: " TO "\r\n",
  "From: " TITLE " \r\n",
  "Subject: Theme\r\n",
  "\r\n",
  "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n",
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n",
  "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=file.txt\r\n",
  "\r\n",
  NULL
};

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    ...
}
```

There was an idea to attach html, but it is also impossible to attach it to a message using this method.

Comment: I believe you need to MIME-encode the attachment. See [RFC 5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322). I think curl has MIME functionality built-in.

Comment: But the file should have been transferred even in a different encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the following excerpt from [this useful example program](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mime.html), you need to use [`curl_mime_filedata()`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_filedata.html) if you want to attach a file to an email:

```c
/* Add the current source program as an attachment. */ 
part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
curl_mime_filedata(part, "smtp-mime.c");
```